# Multilanguage validation in Kohana

Tags: validation, internationalization, kohana, multilingual

Where should I call `__()` -function?  **In Views, or Messages?**

> **1. IN VIEWS**

`Messages`

```
return array
(
    'username' => array(
        'not_empty'  => 'Not empty',
        'min_length' => 'Min length :param2',
        'max_length' => 'Max length :param2',
        'default'    => 'Default',
    ),
);
```

`View`

```
<?php
    foreach ($errors as $field => $message):
    echo '<li>'.$field.': '.__($message).'</li>'; // here
    endforeach;
?>
```

> **2. IN MESSAGES**

`Messages`

```
return array
(
    'username' => array(
        'not_empty'  => __('Not empty'),          // here
        'min_length' => __('Min length :param2'), // here
        'max_length' => __('Max length :param2'), // here
        'default'    => __('Default'),            // here
    ),
);
```

`View`

```
<?php
    foreach ($errors as $field => $message):
    echo '<li>'.$field.': '.$message.'</li>';
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you really want to know

Comment: Read the title and tags. This is Kohana specific question and I want to know should I use translation function __() in Views or Messages?

Comment: @Teneff And this isn't PHP related question, so there shouldn't be PHP tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must translate validation messages (with placeholders) in i18n files. Read [this post](http://www.kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=translate_messages).

Comment: Yes, but where do you call `__()` or do you even need `__()` -function for validation? Normal output text needs to be like `__('Hello World')`, text won't be translated without `__()`. So should I place `__()` functions in messages or views?

Comment: `$validation->errors()` by default calls `__()` for validation messages. See http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Validate#errors ($translate param is TRUE by default). So, just use `foreach($errors as $field => $error) echo $error;`